# Limiting Access to Android 3.2 Tablet Files Through USB

Tags: android, usb

The nice people providing us with encrypted media files do not want bad guys stealing those files (after stealing the tablet).  We will periodically upload new files to the tablet from our server.  When the tablet is turned on, it runs our app and the media files on demand.  Is there a way to limit access to the tablet USB port to our server?  In the alternative, how might we prevent the download of those encrypted files from the tablet?

Answer (score 0):

In short, If the 'bad guys'  have physical device access, they're almost impossible to stop.  Your best bet, IMHO, is through the device management API.  Using that, you can require users of your app to encrypt their device when they aren't logged in, enforce minimum device password strength, and even wipe the device after a certain number of incorrect password attempts.  See [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) for a more detailed explanation.

In this way, if the device is locked, a 'bad guy' won't be able to access internal storage and steal your files.